# Integer type values in ArrayList in XPages

Tags: arraylist, xpages

I would like to create an array list and all values in array should be Integer. 
But at the end I need to sum all values in arrayList just like this below. 
I could not find to correct formula for this. 
is it possible to use using like @Sum or another formule without creating any for loop?

```
var myarraylist:java.util.ArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList();
myarraylist.add(10);
myarraylist.add(20);
myarraylist.add(30);
var result= @Sum(myarraylist);
docTest.replaceItemValue("FaturaTahsil",result);
```

Comment: Based on a number of questions recently, I'd advise getting to grips with Java. You'll find the code for these kinds of questions which you're not finding in SSJS. With the full package names you can use Java within SSJS (as you are with java.util.ArrayList), if you don't want to code specifically in Java. If you want to learn that, there are good introductions in blogs or on NotesIn9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var result` gets calculated correct with your SSJS code. The result is `60`.
`@Sum` works for ArrayLists.

Make sure you store result in correct field and save the document.

Comment: Thank you. 
I relaized that "Allow multiply values" is unchecked.:(